Updating existing state Flow based on other Flow which starts later in ViewModel
I have a StateFlow which holds the ui states in ViewModel. Based on one specific ui state, one another method call is made and this call returns another Flow. I want to update existing StateFlow (which one holds the ui state) according to result of second Flow in ViewModel.
class ScreenViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {

(...)

private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<ScreenUiState>(ScreenUiState.Loading)
val uiState: StateFlow<ScreenUiState> = _uiState

(...)

private fun doOnSuccess(data: List<Item>) {
_uiState.value = ScreenUiState.Success(data)
fetchNewData()
}

private fun fetchNewData() {
viewModelScope.launch {
repository.getNewData()
//The place where to update ui state with new data...
  }
 }
}


class Repository() {
fun getNewItems(): Flow<List<Item>> {
return dataSource.newItems()
}
}

I have seen combine and zip examples but they create another flow. They don't solve my issue. Because I want to update existing UiState Flow.
One approach can be collecting the second Flow and updating the first Flow (the one holds the ui state). But as i understood, flow collecting is not recommended in the ViewModel.
How can i solve that issue? Is there any way to handle it?

You can solve this problem by collecting the second Flow within the ViewModel and updating the existing StateFlow based on its emissions. While you've heard that collecting flows in a ViewModel is not recommended, it's acceptable—and often necessary—as long as you manage the coroutine scope correctly using viewModelScope. This scope is tied to the ViewModel's lifecycle, ensuring that coroutines are canceled when the ViewModel is cleared.

Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] demonstrating the issue you have.
